# Where can I find the training logs of (as many as possible) athletes?

Tags: data-request, sports

Where can I find the training logs of (as many as possible) athletes?

I would like to have that first-hand data, to be able to do some statistical research. Training logs of real athletes, from which perhaps very useful information could be obtained (for instance: how sub-optimal is training once a week with respect to four times? Does it make a huge different for your shoulder strength if you only do bench presses vs doing a lot of overhead work? would I obtain some first-hand conclusion about the number of reps vs strength gain? That kind of things).

Answer (score 2):

Try these:

- [Longitudinal study of the effect of high intensity weight training on aerobic capacity](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00601804)
- [Effect of endurance training on lung function: a longitudinal study](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/48347113_Effect_of_endurance_training_on_lung_function_a_longitudinal_study).

Comment: After a quick look, I don't see data at either of those links. Did I miss it? I believe the original question sought readily useable data.

Comment: @JoeGermuska my apologies. I'm used to contacting researchers for their data on a routine basis. I didn't realize this wasn't acceptable.

Comment: Apology accepted (and I didn't mean to sound like i was demanding one) -- It was an honest question. I suppose that your references are better than nothing.